# Reactive Forms - skip validation on Cancel

Tags: angular, angular-validation

I have a reactive form which has Cancel and Submit buttons:

```
<button (click)="cancel($event)" type="button" class="ui button">Cancel</button>
<button [disabled]="..." type="submit" class="ui button primary">Store</button>
```

and now if I click on a Submit (Store) button validation kicks in - all good. But if I click on Cancel it also trigger validation. I wonder why? I don't need any validation on Cancel. What do I need to do to turn it off?

Comment: Is the form encapsulated by a modal or something? What is the expected behavior when the user hits cancel?

Comment: There's a router guard but otherwise it's just a form. I'd like clicking Cancel do not touch validation at all

Comment: Use both `(mousedown)` and `(click)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply 'reset' the `formControl`s in the parent `formGroup`on cancel button click if that is okay for you.

```
cancel() {
 this.form.reset();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works with event.preventDefault()

```html
<button (click)="cancel($event)">Cancel</button>
```

```
cancel(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
}
```

Comment: I prefer this solution much more than the others. This also really helps if you're looking for buttons like, "+" or "-" (to remove elements from a list) from triggering form validation. And it doesn't seem to have any undesirable side effects!

Answer (score 0):

I would re-initialize the FormGroup when the `Cancel` button is clicked. This would completely wipe the form and force all of the input states to be prestine again. You should be using input states to verify whether they have been used or not if you aren't already. It will prevent validation from running on a form input that hasn't been used yet.

**Component**

```js
constructor() {
    this.Form = initForm();
}

initForm() {
    return this._FormBuilder.group({
        fieldOne: ['', Validators.required]
    })
}
```

**Input**

```
 <div class="ui input" [class.error]="Form.get('fieldOne').dirty && !Form.get('fieldOne').valid">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." formControlName="fieldOne">
</div>
```

**Button**

```
<button (click)="initForm()" type="button" class="ui button">Cancel</button>
```

P.S. it looks like you are using Semantic UI, so my HTML is formatted accordingly. If not you'll need to rework it a little.